# How can I do a files upload like this in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following an article on uploading large files via chunking. Part of the .NET Framework (pre-Core) example code, in the article that handles each file looks as follows:

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
    var FileDataContent = Request.Files[file];
    if (FileDataContent != null && FileDataContent.ContentLength > 0)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

I have since found out that I should rather use `Request.Form.Files`, but then the code:

```
foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
{
    var xx = Request.Form.Files[file];
}
```

gives me a compile error:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' to 'string'

What code can I use that will achieve the equivalent of looping through all uploaded files in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Answer (score 5):

Now (I've tried for ASP.Net Core 1.0 and 2.0) `Request.Form.Files` has type of `IFormFileCollection` which implements `IEnumerable<IFormFile>`. So there is no need anymore to access files dictionary by string key. You basically enumerate instances of `IFormFile` directly like:

```
foreach (IFormFile file in Request.Form.Files)
{
    //  Access properties of a file like file.Name or file.Length
}
```